# Taking string input using BufferedReader

Tags: java

When I take a String input using BufferedReader, for eg.:

```
String a=br.readLine();
```

and after that when I type:

```
 if(a=="hello")
    {//statements}
    else{....}
```

then even if the user enters 'hello' as string a, it never executes the statements in the if block and just jumps to else. I don't face this problem when I directly take a string input in the parameter list of a method without using buffered reader. What is wrong? and how else can I take string input using buffered reader without facing this problem?Please help. 
p.s. there is no syntax error in my program

Answer (score 1):

Use `String#equals` to check `String` content. The `==` operator is used to compare `Object` references.

```
if (a.equals("hello"))
```

or to avoid `NPE`, better to use

```
if ("hello".equals(a)))
```